# Retrieving a fixed range of rows from Postgresql

Tags: postgresql, select, view

I have a query:

```
select qid,ansid,ans from table1 where askerid='something'
```

This query can retrieve many rows. But I want to display only 50 rows at a time and then if the user clicks on `more`, the next 50 rows should be retrieved. I have thought of a query like this :

```
select qid,ansid,ans 
from table1 
where askerid='something' 
limit 100
minus 
select qid,ansid,ans 
from table1 
where askerid='something' 
limit 50
```

I want to know if this is a good query performance-wise and alternate queries that perform better than the above one.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The proper way to do this is using `LIMIT` and `OFFSET`.

Note that for this to work properly, your query will need an `ORDER BY` clause so that the rows are fetched in the same order each time.

Your first query would be:

```
SELECT qid,ansid,ans 
FROM table1 
WHERE askerid='something'
LIMIT 50 OFFSET 0
```

The second query would have an `OFFSET` of 50, as you want to skip the first 50 rows:

```
SELECT qid,ansid,ans
FROM table1 
WHERE askerid='something' 
LIMIT 50 OFFSET 50
```

The `ORDER BY` clause wants adding between the `WHERE` and `LIMIT` clauses.

The Postgres documentation on this is [here](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/queries-limit.html), and mentions that this may not be performant for large `OFFSET` values. It will be ok for small-ish datasets if the `ORDER BY` column is indexed.

Comment: Yeah it says that large offsets can be inefficient. Then suppose I have 10000 rows and I am retrieving 100 rows at a time. Then for the last 100 rows offset - 9900 and limit - 100. So then what is the efficient option for such situations.